# ArcObjects - Will the Post/Reconcile Operations Fire the IObjectClassEvents Event?

Tags: arcobjects

Just wondering if anyone had experience with this before I go down that rabbit hole...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never confirmed, but I don't think it would.  If it does then maybe use IVersionEvents2  to let your class extension knows things are being posted/reconciled.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, that's exactly what I discovered too. I'll just use IDataChanges to iterate through the rows.